# how to get out just a dynamic link out of the random function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, image

i want to take out just the dynamic link, but not all  object from here:

```
    function random_imglink(){
      var myimages=new Array()
      //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
      myimages[1]="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/standalone.swf"
      myimages[2]="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/mobil.swf"
      myimages[3]="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/3b2.swf"

      var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)

      if (ry==0)
         ry=1
         document.write('<embed wmode="transparent" src="'+myimages[ry]+'" height="253" width="440"></embed>')
    }   
    random_imglink()
```

i mean, to make smth like $random_link$ dynamic link so that i can put it in html code as

```
<embed wmode="transparent" src="$random_link$" height="253" width="440"></embed>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you trying to get a return value or some such?

Comment: i mean, now the func works like this, it put the whole embed object, but i want it to write just the dynamic link, so that i can put it in another object out of scipt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function randomItem(theArray) {
    return theArray[Math.floor(theArray.length * Math.random())];
}

myImages = ["some","image","paths"];

var theFlashElement = '<embed wmode="transparent" src="' + randomItem(myImages) + '" height="253" width="440"></embed>';

document.getElementById("flashContainerId").innerHTML = theFlashElement;
```

Comment: please note that you need a <div id="flashContainerId"></div> in your document to make this work

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble figuring out what you're asking, but if you're looking to get just the link from the function (perhaps as a return value) in order to get away from `document.write` (almost always a good idea to get away from that), then:

```
function random_imglink(){
  var myimages=new Array()
  //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
  myimages[1]="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/standalone.swf"
  myimages[2]="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/mobil.swf"
  myimages[3]="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/3b2.swf"

  var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)

  if (ry==0) {
     ry=1;
  }
  return  myimages[ry];
}   
alert(random_imglink()); // alerts one of the three paths above
```

---

**Off-topic:** Here's that function cleaned up some:

```
function random_imglink(){
  //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
  var myimages = [
      "/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/standalone.swf",
      "/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/mobil.swf",
      "/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/3b2.swf"
  ];

  return myimages[Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)];
}   
alert(random_imglink()); // alerts one of the three paths above
```

Changes:

1. Don't rely on semicolon insertion, you'll never be able to minify your scripts (and it's the spawn of the devil anyway).
2. Use array literal.
3. Use indexes 0..2 rather than 1..3
4. As a result of #3 reduce the complexity of generating the index

I haven't factored out the common part of the paths on the assumption that there may be others added later that don't have that common part (`/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/`). If the paths will always start with that, then obviously you could reduce the size of the script by only listing it once and then appending the bit that changes.

Comment: no no, i dont want the link to be alerted, just to show link, or make a code of dynamic link

Comment: @venom: The alert is just to show you what the function returns. Once you have the function's return value, you can do with it what you like -- output an `embed` tag, put it in a link, etc., etc.